# Chromium stack_container for StackString can't work (at least in VisualC++)

Tags: c++, string, stack

### Symptoms

I was investigating using the chromium `stack_container` set specifically the `StackString`. I made a test program with the following:

```
#include <chromium/base/stack_container.h>
int main() {
    StackString<300> s;
    return 0;
}
```

This should create space on the stack and the string would reserve this space.

I was surprised to find, when i added some breakpoints to `allocate` in `StackAllocator` that the stack buffer is never returned to anyone. Ie, the general purpose allocater is always called:

```
pointer allocate(size_type n, void* hint = 0) {
    if (source_ != NULL && !source_->used_stack_buffer_
        && n <= stack_capacity) {
      source_->used_stack_buffer_ = true; // source_ is always NULL
      return source_->stack_buffer();     // and so this is never returned.
    } else {
      return std::allocator<T>::allocate(n, hint); // This is always called.
    }
}
```

### Problem

After further investigation, i found that this is because when the `std::basic_string` type is created (as part of the construction of `StackString`) the VisualC++ implementation stores the allocater into some pair. Then when needing to use it, it copies it into a proxy:

```
void _Alloc_proxy()
    {   // construct proxy
    typename _Alty::template rebind<_Container_proxy>::other
        _Alproxy(_Getal()); // Copies the allocator!
    _Myproxy() = _Unfancy(_Alproxy.allocate(1)); // NOTE this for a later point.
    ...
```

The copy constructor of the `StackAllocator` will set the copies stack pointer to NULL. Hence the `StackString` could never work.

Furthermore, if the `StackString`didnt have this problem, it immediatly allocates space of 1, meaning after you add anything, it will quickly grow and suffer the same problem anyway.

### Questions

1. Is this a bug, and if so by whom, VisualC++ or chromium?
2. If the first symptom doesn't occur, wouldn't the second item be a problem for most compilers anyway?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that StackString was removed from the Chromium project: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=709273

But it's rather not a bug but some kind of optimization for a small string.

Visual Studio 2015/2017 will allocate a 16-byte std::_Container_proxy in the heap when compiling in "Debug" even for an empty string.
In "Release", we won't use the heap memory for the StackString.

I tested it with this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <new>
#include "stack_container.h"

std::size_t memory = 0;
std::size_t alloc = 0;

void* operator new(std::size_t s) throw(std::bad_alloc) {
    // Put breakpoint here
    memory += s;
    ++alloc;
    return malloc(s);
}

void operator delete(void* p) throw() {
    --alloc;
    free(p);
}

void PrintMem_Info()
{
    std::cout << "memory = " << memory << '\n';
    std::cout << "alloc = " << alloc << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    StackString<256> str;
    PrintMem_Info();
    str->append("Hello World!");
    PrintMem_Info();
    str[0] = '1';
    str[1] = '2';
}
```

And my solution is:

```
pointer allocate(size_type n, void* hint = 0) {
#if defined(_MSC_VER)
    if (n > stack_capacity)
    {
        n = stack_capacity;
    }
#endif // if defined(_MSC_VER)
    if (source_ != nullptr && !source_->used_stack_buffer_
        && n <= stack_capacity) {
        source_->used_stack_buffer_ = true;
        return source_->stack_buffer();
    }
    else {
        return std::allocator<T>::allocate(n, hint);
    }
}
```